# "Path cannot be empty" error when rendering a template in Ember

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I have [an application](https://github.com/wholcomb/habit_tracker) ([live](http://doh.cloudant.com/habits/_design/habits/index.html)) where I am attempting to use Ember to persist a data model to CouchDB. I have been working through the [Ember tutorial](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/displaying-model-data/) and am stuck trying to render data.

When the page loads I get an error: "Error while loading route: Error: Path cannot be empty"

My `application.js` is:

```
window.Habits = Ember.Application.create()
window.Habits.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend()
```

`router.js` is:

```
Habits.Router.map( function() {
    this.resource( 'habits', { path: '/' } )
} )

Habits.HabitsRoute = Ember.Route.extend( {
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find( 'habit' )
    }
} )
```

The model, `models/habit.js` is:

```
Habits.Habit = DS.Model.extend( {
    name: DS.attr( 'string' ),
    isCompleted: DS.attr( 'boolean' )
} )

Habits.Habit.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Pipe of Tobacco',
        isCompleted: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Pipe of Marijuana',
        isCompleted: false
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: '80mg Latuda',
        isCompleted: false
    }
]
```

Finally, my HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Habit Tracker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/couchapp/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
<script src="/_utils/script/sha1.js"></script>
    <script src="/_utils/script/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/couchapp/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="/_utils/script/jquery.couch.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/couchapp/jquery.couchLogin.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/couchapp/jquery.couchProfile.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/couchapp/md5.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/couchapp/jquery.mustache.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/couchapp/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/couchapp/ember.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/couchapp/ember-states.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/couchapp/ember-data-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/couchapp/couchdb_adapter.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/couchapp/sprintf.js"></script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="habits">
      <div id="account"></div>

      <h1>Habit Tracker</h1>

      <div id="profile"></div>

      <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
          <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#habits" data-ajax="false">Habits</a></li>
              <li><a href="#mood" data-ajax="false">Mood</a></li>
              <li><a href="#events" data-ajax="false">Events</a></li>
              <li><a href="#stats" data-ajax="false">Stats</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div id="habits" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">                                                                                                                                                  
              {{#each}}                                                                                                                                                                                  
                <li><a href="#">
                  <span>{{name}}</span>
                  <span data-role="timer">2013-12-17T03:24:00</span>
                </a></li>                                                                                                                                                                                
              {{/each}}                                                                                                                                                                                  
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div id="mood">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
              <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div id="events">
          </div>
          <div id="stats">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </script>
    <script src="script/timer.jquery" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script/router.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script/models/habit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="vendor/couchapp/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of jQuery used by the couchapp example was too old. I upgraded to the most recent version and the routing error went away.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make your main application template with your outlet like this

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
     {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Then in your habits template, you need to change it like this:

```
 {{#each in model}}
    <li>
       <a href="#">
            <span>{{name}}</span>
            <span data-role="timer">2013-12-17T03:24:00</span>
       </a>
    </li>
 {{/each}}
```

Since you're iterating over the items in your model, you need specify that's the property you're using.

PS: Can't access you're live example because it requires a username/password.